# Performance tuning of JSF and RichFaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm in the process of optimizing JSF and Richfaces by finetuning the many parameters but very few documentation actually explains what all those parameters do:

when using the following to parameter

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

this one should be turned off

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

why is it exactly? I cant find any explanation in the documentation (same goes for other parameters, like impact when turning on neko parser etc.)